# Slimming fat viewcontroller - Barcode scanner not working anymore

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button on my app that opens upp a barcode scanner, I can then scan an item and it prints the barcode etc.

My Viewcontroller was getting very full of codes, and i just wanted to create another class to seperate and make my code easier to read. So i put all of the barcodescanner code in the class "Partnyallen" and kept my button in class "NewViewController". I can open the barcode, but as soon as i scan an item or even if i press the "cancel" button inside, it just freezes. What could the problem be?

Thankful for any help!

```
import AVFoundation
import QRCodeReader
import Alamofire


class Partynallen: UIViewController, QRCodeReaderViewControllerDelegate {

    lazy var readerVC: QRCodeReaderViewController = {
    let builder = QRCodeReaderViewControllerBuilder {
    //change object to scan and the initial position of the camera
        $0.reader = QRCodeReader(metadataObjectTypes: [.qr, .ean13], captureDevicePosition: .back)
    // Configure the view controller (optional)
    $0.showTorchButton = true
    $0.showSwitchCameraButton = false
    $0.showCancelButton = true
    $0.showOverlayView = true //shows the square area of the QRCode Scanner
        $0.rectOfInterest = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
    }
    return QRCodeReaderViewController(builder: builder)
    }()
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        readerVC.delegate = self
    }
    
    func reader(_ reader: QRCodeReaderViewController, didScanResult result: QRCodeReaderResult) {
    //code to be added
        reader.stopScanning()
        //print(result)
        //print(result.value)
        //barcode = result.value
       //Apifetch(code: "URL")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func readerDidCancel(_ reader: QRCodeReaderViewController) {
    //code to be added
        reader.stopScanning()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}



class NewViewController: UIViewController {
    
var partynallen: Partynallen?

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
           partynallen = Partynallen() // DONT KNOW IF THIS IS CORRECT? 
    }



        @IBAction func scan(_ sender: UIButton) {

            partynallen.readerVC.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
            present(partynallen.readerVC, animated: true)
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: A helper class should _not_ be a view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got 3 ViewControllers `NewViewController`, `QRCodeReaderViewController` and `Partynallen`. But actually you never present `Partynallen` and just use it as a delegate for the scanner, instead you only present the `readerVC`. So, when `readerDidCancel(:)` is called, you try to dismiss `Partynallen`, which isn’t presented.

Using a ViewController that only acts as the scanner-delegate seems to be a bit too much. You could maybe remove the UIViewController base-class (if it isn‘t required by the scanner-delegate-protocol). And because the delegate-functions, e.g `readerDidCancel(:),` provide the scanner-vc, you could just use that vc to dismiss itself.